# TemplateDoesNotExist | django 3.0.1 ,python 3.6

Tags: django, django-templates, python-3.6

I am new to Django , I'm working on system Windows 10 , Django version 3.0.1 ,python 3.6 I tried to use all the relevant solutions provided for this problem , but unfortunately none of those resolve my problem .
I made a folder named **templates** in **myapp** and **"index.html"** inside it, I write some lines of code in my **views.py** file as

```
from django.shortcuts import render  
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader 
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

here is my **settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = (os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))



TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**Traceback error **

```
Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: E:\djangoLearning\myproject\myapp\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: E:\djangoLearning\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: E:\djangoLearning\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: E:\djangoLearning\myproject\myapp\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\djangoLearning\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\djangoLearning\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "E:\djangoLearning\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\djangoLearning\myproject\myapp\views.py", line 9, in index
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
  File "E:\djangoLearning\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /index/
Exception Value: index.html
```

workng directory

```
myproject
myapp
  templates
      index.html
```

Comment: You said you created templates under `myprojects` directory but on your working directory it is under `myapp`. But you can try `template = loader.get_template('myapp/index.html')` if it is under myapp.

Comment: Thanks ,  I edited it, actually templates directory is under myapp only

Answer (score 2):

**Step:-1)** Go to your project **settings.py** file

Add the following template list of configuration:

```
 TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

**Step:--2)** Go to your app >> Create **templates** folder >> create a folder by your_app_name again>> create your template file like: index.html

```
 Your_APP_Name
     |-templates
         |-Your_APP_Name
                |-index.html
```

Say, you have a blog app. So the structure will be like:

```
 blog
     |-templates
         |-blog
                |-index.html
```

**Step:-3)** Now you may call the **template** file precisely in render method. So the view will be look like:

```
   from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
   from django.http import HttpResponse

   def index(request):
       return render(request,'your_app_name/index.html')
```

Comment: Yeah your solution worked , but why do we need to create myapp directory again under templates directory ?

Comment: @PrashantRajput, Actually this is for Django template searching way. We could use directly under the app_name/index.html . Django template rules is that it search for template folder in the project so where it will get index.html it will assume that index.html. Because same template file name can be written for other files also. So if you create the subdirectory with the same name again then it will precise your template file. Actually you will get details here:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/#Now_we_might_be_able